# Align elements relative to each other

Tags: css, position, css-position

Basically I'm wondering if you can position 2 elements relative to each other.
I have a h1 and h2 inside a div, I want to align the h2 to the right side of the h1

[image]

html

```
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>Header with some text</h1>
    <h2>Other header</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</header>
```

css

```
header { 
  width: 960px;
}

div {
  width: 318px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 200px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to **wrap the headings** in an *extra* `inline-block` div and the apply `text-align:right`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>
I'm a really long h1 tag
</h1>
    <h2>
 Short h2 tag
</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly on it's own but when I try it in my example it just aligns both h1 and h2 to the div, fiddle to show what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/kv1ym4zf/

Comment: Should work...https://jsfiddle.net/yL4xhcbb/1/ You seem to have omitted the extra wrapper.

Comment: @Steven read again first sentence of answer ... float would work too, but an extra wrapper is needed any how : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwoXMw (was about to be my answer .. but similar to Paulies ..)

Comment: Ah yea thnx just figured out myself https://jsfiddle.net/kv1ym4zf/, tired brain tends to skip here and there :D

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```css
.some_class > * {
  display:inline-block;

  }
```

```html
<div class="some_class">
  <h1>some text</h1>
  <h2> Some other text </h2>
  
  </div>
```